# return IEnumerable as result of async function calls

Tags: c#, async-await, ienumerable

I have a function that gets a sequence of items:

```
List<MyType> GetPage(int pageNr) {...}
```

To get all available items you could do something like:

```
IEnumerable<MyType> FetchMyItems()
{
    int pageNr = 0;
    var fetchedItems = GetPage(pageNr);
    while (fetchedItems.Any()
    {   // there are items to return
        // yield return the fetched items: 
        foreach (var fetchedItem in fetchedItems)
            yield return fetchedItems;

        // get the next page
         ++pageNr;
         fetchedItems = GetPage(pageNr)
    }
}
```

Using this method, my users won't have to fetch the items per page anymore, if they need only a few items only the first page will be fetched. More pages will be fetched automatically when they need more items. The disadvantage is of course that I sometimes fetch a few more items that won't be used.

### I want an async version for this

So I have the following GetPage:

```
async Task<List<MyType>> GetPageAsync(int pageNr) {...}
```

From what I understand from IEnumerable, is that it doesn't create the resulting sequence, it only creates the possibility to enumerate this sequence.

This enumerating is done explicitly using 'foreach', or implicitly using LINQ functions like 'ToList', 'ToArray', but also functions like 'FirstOrDefault', 'Any', `Sum`.

```
var fetchItemTasks = FetchMyItemsAsync();
foreach (var fetchItemTask in fetchedItemTasks)
{
      MyType fetchedItem = await fetchItemTask;
      Process(fetchedItem);
}
```

Or if you do this low level:

```
var myitemsEnumerable = fetchMyItemsAsync();
// don't await yet, only create the possibility to enumerate

var enumerator = myItemsEnumerable.GetEnumerator();
while (enumerator.MoveNext())
{   // there is an item available in current:
    Task<MyType> task = enumerator.Current;
    return task;
}
```

Looking at this, It seems that the function should not return `Task<IEnumerable<MyType>>` but `IEnumerable<Task<MyType>>`, if you want to access an element you'll have to await for this.

Therefore, the function that returns the possibility to enumerate over awaitable items is not async for itself. You don't await for the enumerable, this enumerable can be created without accessing slow providers like a database. The items in the enumerable sequence are awaitable:

```
IEnumerable<Task<MyType>> FetchMyItems()
{
    int pageNr = 0;
    Task<List<MyType>> fetchItemTask = GetPageAsync(pageNr);
```

And now? If I `await fetchItemTask`, the items are already local nothing to await for anymore. If I `fetchItemTask.Wait()`, the function blocks.

Comment: *the items are already local nothing to await for anymore* What does that mean?

Comment: What you need is async enumerator, which does not yet has language support (here is a proposal: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/async-streams.md), but you can of course use this pattern without such support (without foreach, with more verbose syntax).

Comment: In the end I wanted to create extension functions like `ToListAsync`, `ToArrayAsync`, `CountAsync`,  `AnyAsync` etc. But for them I need a basic IEnumerable. I'll read your proposal and check if creating my own `EnumeratorAsync<TSource>` would be the way to go

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation of async/await pattern doesn't look correct.

`GetPageAsync` signature is fine:

```
async Task<List<MyType>> GetPageAsync(int pageNr) {...}
```

Now, if you want to call this method asynchronously you have to use `await` keyword, which will suspend the executing method and return control to its caller until the `GetPageAsync` result is ready:

```
List<MyType> items = await GetPageAsync(pageNr);
```

or

```
Task<List<MyType>> getPageTask = GetPageAsync(pageNr);

// Some other stuff

List<MyType> items = await getPageTask;
```

But note that `await` keyword can only be used inside a method that is itself `async`.

Probably I don't realize the whole idea of your application async model, but in any case, I would recommend having a look at this [MSDN article on asynchronous programming with async/await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/hh191443(v=vs.120)) first.

Comment: The problem is, that I don't know how many items my caller want. Does he only use `FirstOrDefault`? Will he `Take(2000)`? Hence I don't want to fetch more pages than needed. If he'll enumerate only the first few items, then fetching one page will be enough. Entity Framework has` ListAsync`, `FirstOrDefaultAsync` etc. To be able to create similar functions I need a base async function that returns the IEnumerable